# Using PHP on macOS Monterey - many homebrew errors on reinstall after updating OS

Tags: php, macos, macos-monterey

I made the seemingly bad decision to update to macOS Monterey `12.3.1`, and am having a hell of a time trying to get PHP working on it again. From what I've seen, Apple has decided that PHP is deprecated - at least from their machines, and they removed every php version and setting that I had set up for all my Laravel and Wordpress projects!

I tried reinstalling PHP using homebrew but I got a lot of errors about certain packages not being able to be downloaded due to authorization denial?

So then I attempted to uninstall and reinstall Homebrew, and I did the following:

**Install Homebrew**

```
/bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install.sh)"
```

**Add the following to zshrc**

```
eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
```

**Test brew version to see if it's working**

```
brew --version
```

**Run brew doctor to make sure everything is configured correctly**

```
brew doctor
```

I also saw that it was likely that there would be libraries missing and that i should reinstall open ssl so i did that as well:

```
brew install openssl
```

Then for PHP I ran:

```
brew tap shivammathur/php
```

and then

```
brew install shivammathur/php/php@7.4
brew install shivammathur/php/php@8.0
```

and I even restarted the php services just in case

```
brew services restart shivammathur/php/php@7.4 
brew services restart shivammathur/php/php@8.0
```

Then I ran

```
php -v
```

and I got the following error:

```
zsh: command not found: php
```

and `which php` says `php not found`

what the heck!

I then tried to unlink php and force a link to 7.4:

```
brew unlink php && brew link --overwrite --force php@7.4
```

and I got the following brew error:

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/php
```

I tried digging into fixing this keg issue but i haven't been able to figure it out, do you have any suggestions on next steps

Answer (score 0):

Check that Homebrew's bin directory i.e. `$(brew --prefix)/bin` is in your PATH.

If you want to link PHP 7.4, run

```
brew link --overwrite --force php@7.4
```

If you get an error mentioning that it is already linked, you can relink it by unlinking it first and linking it again to be sure. Make sure you unlink the correct version.

```
brew unlink php@7.4
brew link --overwrite --force php@7.4
```